# how to select hidden value from dropdown using webdriver, selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I am totally new to this concept, so please help me.

I want to select a value (D) from dd and click it.

```
<select id="projectTypeNameDropdown"
                class="singleSelectProjectTypeDropdown chzn-select">
                <option value="">--Select a ProjectType--</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>

 </select>
```

With the below code, I am getting index and value both:

```
countries=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("projectTypeNameDropdown")).options
for index, value in enumerate(countries):
        print(value)
```

and if I use the below code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='projectTypeNameDropdown']/option[text()='D']").click()
```

I get an error that says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

please help me to select the hidden value and click it.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `assert len(driver.find_elements_by_id('projectTypeNameDropdown')) <= 1`. Do you get exception?

Comment: no am not getting any exception

Comment: This is the code behind
  <form id="addProjectForm" action=insertProject
   method="post">
   <input id="mergeprojectId"
        name="mergeProjectID" type="hidden"value="" />     
   <input id="isNotRefrenceProject"
                                name="isNotRefrenceProject" type="hidden"
                                value="true" />         
   <select id="projectTypeNameDropdown"
    class="singleSelectProjectTypeDropdown chzn-select">
    <option value="">--Select a ProjectType--</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>

Comment: The dropdown has a search txtbox also

Comment: after many trails , i have used this code and is workig successfully o chrome driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('projectTypeNameDropdown').style.display=''")
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='projectTypeNameDropdown']/option[text()='D']"))).click()